# Password created with New-AzureADServicePrincipalPasswordCredential not visible in AD Portal?

Tags: azure-activedirectory

There is a Powershell command `New-AzureADServicePrincipalPasswordCredential` in the AzureAD module which adds a password credential to an Active Directory Service Principal (and an analogous command for Certificate credentials).

I can use this command to add a password to a Service Principal, and it appears to work (the password can be used for authentication), but I don't see any place in the AD Portal (the set of web forms for directly administering Azure AD online) that shows these credentials, let alone allows modifying them. Note that in the portal, Service Principals show up as Enterprise Applications.

The App Registration has a Credentials page where the corresponding information can be see for the App Registration (such credentials can be used by all Service Principals based on the App Registration).

Am I missing something? Is this ability so new that it is not fully supported in the Portal? So old it is deprecated and I should not be doing this? The latter seems unlikely since, barring this ability, the only credentials would be those of the App Registration, and any tenant that instantiates the App Registration as its own Service Principal would use the same credentials (i.e. password).